# Kafka Connect Hive integration does not create Hive table

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following kafka connector config:

```
{
  "name": "some-topic-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "some-topic",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://hadoopams1",
    "logs.dir": "apps/kafka-connect-preview/some-topic.logs",
    "topics.dir": "apps/kafka-connect-preview/some-topic.db",
    "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop/conf",
    "flush.size": "1000000",
    "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "86400000",
    "hive.integration": "true",
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://metastore-1.hadoop-1.foobar.com:9083",
    "hive.database": "preview",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry.preview.foobar.com",
    "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "partition.duration.ms": "86400000",
    "path.format": "'dt'=YYYYMMdd",
    "partition.field.name": "dt"
  }
}
```

I've verified that the data is written to HDFS successfully, but for some reason the table in Hive is not being created. From the logs, I can't see any errors in Kafka Connect.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some configuration or a requirement that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/issues/272#issuecomment-358331505) (feature?) that the `HdfsSinkConnector` does not create a table in Hive in case the `logs.dir` and `topics.dir` already exists. This can, for example, happen if you decided to enable hive integration at some point after the connector was already created.

There is also a [pull request](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/412) that fixes this issue, but it has not been merged.

So either

- you build your own `HdfsSinkConnector` based on the pull request linked above
- you rename the directories, recreate the connector, wait until the Hive tables have been created and then move the tables back (difficult in a production environment, of course)
- or you create the table manually